# Need help converting ASN1(x509)

Tags: python, converters

Stuck on trying to convert my outcome from "20190211004950Z"(ASN1) to "2019-02-11"(Standard date) Before anyone asks, it's just a simple SSL expiry check and the date creation/expiration dates keep being output like I posted earlier.

My code looks like this

```
          **

    **import OpenSSL
import socket
import ssl
from pprint import pprint
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import datetime


def get_certificate(port=443, timeout=10):
    """

    :param timeout:
    :type port: object
    """
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    # test=(host,port)
    host = input("enter a URL")
    conn = socket.create_connection(address=(host, port))

    sock = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=host)

    sock.settimeout(timeout)
    try:
        der_cert = sock.getpeercert(True)
    finally:
        sock.close()
    return ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(der_cert)


certificate = get_certificate()
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate)


result = {
    'subject': dict(x509.get_subject().get_components()),
    'issuer': dict(x509.get_issuer().get_components()),
    'serialNumber': x509.get_serial_number(),
    'version': x509.get_version(),
    'notBefore': str(x509.get_notBefore()),
    'notAfter': str(x509.get_notAfter())
}

extensions = (x509.get_extension(i) for i in range(x509.get_extension_count()))
extension = (e.get_short_name() for e in extensions)
result.update(name=extension)
pprint(result)**

**
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you share the surrounding code, give some context? What does your string parsing/formatting have to do with ```x509```? What does “ASN1(x509)” mean?

Comment: edited the original code to provide the whole thing

Comment: Maybe i’m blind, but where should the parsing take place in your code?

Comment: 'notBefore': str(x509.get_notBefore()),
    'notAfter': str(x509.get_notAfter())

Comment: did any of the answers end up helping you?

Comment: unfortunately no, I've still yet to get a proper output

Comment: what kind of output are you getting? Any errors?

Comment: no errors, just the same 20190211004950Z style output

Comment: That is so incredibly weird. Do you want to start a chat room so you can share your updated code and i’ll take a look?

Comment: That might help, thank you

Comment: Do you want to use stackoverflow chat, Slack, something else?

Comment: Why not replace some code?  You can use this line to tidy up the code: `OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der_cert)`.  Put it after the `der_cert = sock.getpeercert(True)`

Comment: I found a neat `attribute` of the `OpenSSL.crypto.X509` cert.  To get a simple `Common Name` use: `leaf_cert.get_subject().CN`

Answer (score 2):

You want to extract `YYYY-MM-DD` from `20190211004950Z`.

It's one line only:

```py
import datetime

asn1_time = '20190211004950Z'

datetime.datetime.strptime(asn1_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%fZ').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

result = '20190211004950Z'

formatted_result = '{}-{}-{}'.format(result[:4],result[4:6],result[6:8])

Comment: ok so I'm feeling a tad bit stupid, cause where im trying to put the code in it's not working. Im just getting the same result as always

Comment: can you provide a bit more code? Where is the output?

Comment: @Minchey this solution also works. It's string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Is your string guaranteed to always follow the format: 4 digits for the year + 2 digits for the month + digits the day? What about all those characters that comes after, are they relevant? What are they determined by?

For now, here is a solution which assumes that the date follows the same format, and that the rest of the string should be ignored:

```py
import datetime


parse_format = ‘%Y%m%d’
out_format = ‘%Y-%m-%d’

str_1 = ‘20190211004950Z’

parse_date_res = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_1[:8], parse_format)

date_str_out = parse_date_res.strftime(out_format)
```

This code parses the string into a date object first, since I wasn’t completely sure if you just wanted a string as output. In any case, if there is nothing stopping you from using a date object then you probably should!

Answer (score 0):

The outcome from `'notAfter': str(x509.get_notAfter())` is not an asn1 string. It would be "b'20190211004950Z'" in your case for example. By using decode() instead of str() method would solve the problem. Other than that @maxadamo solution would work perfect for me. Thank you.

```
'notAfter': x509.get_notAfter().decode()
```